# Reading a large Excel file by OpenXML

Tags: .net, vb.net, openxml

I am working on a project in which i am reading few cells from an excel file using OpenXML SDK in VB.Net and storing it in DataTable.
It works just fine for the medium sized and small files
however when when i try to open a large file of size 107MB, i get an OutOfMemory exception after reading through few sheets. I am able to open the file by double clicking(it takes a while though)
Below are the code that i am using. Please let me know if i can improve the process of reading by reducing the memory consumption

```
Dim CellRage As String() = {"AG65", "AG281", "AG335", "AG389", "AG443", "AG497", "AG551", "AG800", "AG913", "AG1081", "AG1165", "AG1305"}
Dim CellValue(13) As String

Using myWorkbook As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, False)
     workbookPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart

     For Each worksheetpart As WorksheetPart In workbookPart.WorksheetParts
       For count As Integer = 0 To CellRage.GetUpperBound(0) -1
             CellValue(count) = CellValue(workbookPart, sheetName, CostCellRage(count - 2)) 
       Next
       'After few sheets throws OutofMemory Exception
     Next
End Using

Private Shared Function GetCellValue(workbookPart As WorkbookPart, sheetName As String, cellAddress As String) As String
        Dim theCell As Cell
        Dim wsPart As WorksheetPart
        Dim worksheet As Sheet
        Dim value As String
        Dim stringTablePart As SharedStringTablePart = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart

        worksheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants(Of Sheet).Where(Function(s) s.Name = sheetName).FirstOrDefault
        wsPart = CType(workbookPart.GetPartById(worksheet.Id), WorksheetPart)
        theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants(Of Cell).Where(Function(c) c.CellReference = cellAddress).FirstOrDefault

        If theCell.ChildElements.Count = 0 Then
            Return ""
        End If

        value = theCell.CellValue.Text

        If (theCell.DataType IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (theCell.DataType.ToString() = "s") Then
            value = stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements(Int32.Parse(value)).InnerText
        End If

        Return value

    End Function
```

Thanks for looking into this

Comment: Are you keeping the tables/data from each sheet while looping? I expect you're hitting the .NET limit for memory usage for your application. You may have to do some chunking/paging, unfortunately.

Comment: I am not storing too much of data into the datatable. only 12 cell values from each sheet (30 sheeets)

Comment: We might need to see more of your code to give good suggestions. However, if you have a static list of known columns you are reading in it will be more efficient to read them into a small typed class within a list.

Comment: JocelC Added full set of code

Comment: Consider using XDocument to parse the document without OOXML or at least parse the part with cell data. Looking at your code it shouldn't be that difficult to pull it off

Comment: Can you please direct me to a sample. Another thing is i am not allowed to use any 3rd party libraries other than Microsoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that your code is reading each sheet into memory which is eventually leading to you using too much memory.

As Jesper points out you can use a [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) approach rather than the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) approach you are currently using. To read an Excel document using OpenXML with a SAX approach you can use the `OpenXmlReader` class. This will read the file in a more memory efficient way by handling sections of the XML at a time rather than the whole DOM which should allow you to process large files.

The `OpenXmlReader` reads the XML contents of the file part in XML chunks; think of it like reading a file using a `Stream`. We can't jump to an arbitrary cell as we haven't read the whole document yet. Instead what we need to do is read each row and ignore the rows we don't want. Once we have the row we are interested in we have the entire row XML available so at this point we can jump directly to the cells within that row that we are interested in.

```
Dim desiredColumnNumber As Integer = 33
Dim cellRange As Integer() = New Integer() {65, 281, 335, 389, 443, 497, _
551, 800, 913, 1081, 1165, 1305}

Using reader As OpenXmlReader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart)
    While reader.Read()
        'we want to find the first row
        If reader.ElementType = GetType(Row) Then
            Do
                If Not cellRange.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(CUInt(row.RowIndex))) Then
                    'we're not interested in this row so continue
                    Continue Do
                End If

                Dim row As Row = DirectCast(reader.LoadCurrentElement(), Row)

                If row.HasChildren Then
                    'get cell in column AG
                    Dim cell As Cell = DirectCast(row.ChildElements(desiredColumnNumber), Cell)
                    'do something with the cell...
                End If
                'move to the next row
            Loop While reader.ReadNextSibling()
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

In the code above I have split your cell ranges into a cell number (`desiredCellNumber`) and an array of `Integer` (`cellRange`) that stores the number of each row we are interested in (if you can't split this in your original code you'll have to convert each cell reference into the correct format).

After that we then check the `RowIndex` property on each row to see if it exists in the `cellRange`. If not then we move on to the next row but if it is a row we are interested we can access the cells by accessing the `Row.ChildElements` property. In the code above we are only interested in column 33 so we read that cell value using `row.ChildElements(desiredColumnNumber)`.

As an aside, when I'm dealing with large files like this I usually read the `SharedStringTablePart` into a `Dictionary` or similar first and then read from the there when I need to get a string value. Obviously the amount of memory this consumes depends heavily on the contents of your Excel file so you might want to do something cleverer to minimise the memory used when storing the Shared Strings. The code for reading the shared strings is (almost) identical to the above:

```
Dim sharedStrings As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)()
If stringTablePart IsNot Nothing Then
    Using reader As OpenXmlReader = OpenXmlReader.Create(stringTablePart)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While reader.Read()
            If reader.ElementType = GetType(SharedStringItem) Then
                Dim sharedStringItem As SharedStringItem = DirectCast(reader.LoadCurrentElement(), SharedStringItem)
                sharedStrings.Add(i), If(sharedStringItem.Text IsNot Nothing, sharedStringItem.Text.Text, String.Empty))
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End While
    End Using
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Petelids! In my original code i am only reading a specific Cell address. Can you please let me know how i can do this with xmlReader.

Comment: Hi @Sathish, I've updated the post with a (hopefully) better explanation and a new code sample that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks again Petelids! for some reasons it is not navigating to all the rows that i have in the excel sheet

Comment: Hi @Sathish, the code above will ignore all rows except row 33 (as the cell values in your question only mentioned row AG).

Comment: AG is the column here which is fixed and rows are in the array

Comment: The problem is it does not scan through all the rows or columns. if a file has a blank row or columns it is skipping that

Comment: I got the columns and rows mixed up so I was only looking for cells on row 33. I've updated the code so it now looks for any rows that are in the `cellRange` array. Once it has a row it reads column AG (indexed using `desiredColumnNumber`).

Comment: The problem which i am facing is not able to skip the rows which are not required as the excel row starts from where at least one value is present. But for now Thank you so much as it is at least reading without any exception

Comment: So you have gaps in the rows meaning the count will be out? In that case you could change the if from `If Not cellRange.Contains(currentRowNumber) Then` to `If Not cellRange.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(CUInt(row.RowIndex))) Then`. Let me know if that works and I'll update the answer to reflect it. This has the benefit of not needing the `currentRowNumber`.

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN! I have added updated code based on your suggestions. Is there any way to further improve the performance by using XMLDOC.GetElementByID here.

Comment: Glad to help. Unfortunately you can't use GetElementById as are not loading the entire document in one go, we are just loading row by row to prevent your memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

Openxml SDK uses a 'DOM-approach' when loading files into memory.

For processing large amounts of data, you should consider using a SAX approach like the XmlReader.

Of course, XmlReader is not a part of the OpenXml SDK, but it should give you better performance and a much lower memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks Jesper! if you can share me an example, it would be great

Comment: @Sathish, there is comprehensive examples on how to use the XmlReader on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx . One idea could be be to use the OpenXml SDK to navigate the parts of the OpenXml package and then use the XmlReader to process the contents of the parts itself.