# How to read an xml in parts using XmlReader?

Tags: c#, openxml, xmlreader

I have the following extension method to read rows from an excel file. However, the excel file is too large (more than 500K rows and 900 columns) and I was hoping if there is anyway to read the excel file in parts (e.g. 5K rows at a time).

```
static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamRows(this OpenXmlPart part)
    {
        using (StreamReader stringReader = new StreamReader(part.GetStream()))
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
        {
            xmlReader.MoveToContent();

            while (!xmlReader.EOF)
            {
                if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.Name == "row")
                {
                    XElement el = XElement.ReadFrom(xmlReader) as XElement;
                    if (el != null)
                    {
                        yield return el;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlReader.Read();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of using 'yeild' I tried adding the XElements to a List (for every 5K rows) and returning the List, but that took more time to execute than desired.

I am out of ideas and any help is appreciated.

Comment: With that code it should already be read in parts (row by row, in streamed manner). What problem exactly you have?

Comment: My [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829801/reading-a-large-excel-file-by-openxml/24865391#24865391) shows how to read a large Excel file using OpenXml. It's in VB but it's easy enough to convert.

Comment: @Evk The current code returns an IEnumerable of all rows (500K) and when I try to iterate it takes a lot of time. What I am looking to do is call this function in a loop so that it reads 5k rows at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ClosedXML. You can find this here: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/ and NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/

This library completly support operations on Excel documents (after version 2007, e.g .xlsx files)

Have fun ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help Damian. The problem I have is that I cannot use any new libraries/packages and have to stick to what is being used. :(

Comment: So try to implement i variable, and increment this in every loop, then check if (i >= 500) { break; }